# How to create WPF Application Preloader (like one on this Word 2010)?

Tags: c#, wpf, preloader, splash-screen

How to create WPF Application Preloader (like one on this Word 2010 Prt Scrn)? Drag able and Close able=)

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/pword.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have WPF spalsh screens. Its just a normal window that runs at startup an listens for 'started' event and disappears.

Comment: I'm pretty sure WPF's built-in splash screen support, if that's what you're referring to, just displays a bitmap -- does it support dragging and closing?

Answer (score 0):

WPF splash screens is only an Image to do a dragable & closable one I guess that you do it as a window that is the first to show and then in the background the app windows is created to at last be displayed and close the "splash".